# AngularJs Cookie : Share across multiple tabs

Tags: angularjs

I am developing an angjs application.
Used angjs 1.6.

Following is my code to create a cookie

```
$cookies.put('globals', $rootScope.globals);
```

When i open a new tab, I dont find this cookie variable "globals".

How to share cookies across multiple tabs?

Comment: is it showing some error in console ?

Answer (score 2):

cookies are document specific. So, you are not getting in other tab. Please go for [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) or use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

and one more thing is even you want to store non-prmitive data(object, array etc) in cookies/storage, you must stringfy before pushing and should be parsed after getting.

eg: `$cookies.put('globals', JSON.stringify({name: 'My_name'}));`

```
var myName = JSON.parse($cookies.get('globals'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps you out:

```
$cookies.put('globals', $rootScope.globals, {domain: 'yourdomainhere'});
```

Comment: I think by default it will be base url. So we dont need to pass it explicitly. Correct?

Comment: yes, but try passing the domain, so if it's on your dev environment, pass 'localhost'